# How do I close Chats tabs in Skype for Business for Mac?

Tags: skype

On the Windows Skype for Business client, to the right of each tab there is an X that allows closing the tab so it no longer shows in the list.  I have not been able to find a way to close tabs in the Mac client, despite extensive searching.

(It is possible to re-use exiting tabs when continuing to talk to someone, but if they start a new conversation with you or switch to a different device, it creates a new tab.  After using the client for one day, I have 5 tabs from one co-worker. I'd like to make the old ones go away.)

OS X 10.11.6 / El Capitan and Skype for Business 16.0.3638

Comment: Too bad, tabs are gone now with the latest public release :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that clicking the tab once selects the tab and moves the cursor to the chat box. A second click on the tab selects the tab, then you can press the delete key to delete the tab.

Comment: That does it!  I had someone else tell me too, and was coming back to answer my own question.  Some very odd UI interactions in this app; not quite Mac-standard, but not exactly like the Windows version either.  Someday I'll figure out how to send an image... not worth cluttering here.

Answer (score -1):

Double-click.  It opens in another window.  Then you get the normal interactions.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different and taking the time to post an answer!  It's helpful to *expand* on your answer to further explain/clarify what you are attempting to communicate.